# WCF service binds at 0:0:0:0 instead of dns alias

Tags: wcf, ip, net.tcp

We have a cluster where to WCF services are running as a resource each in a separated resource group. These groups have a dns alias named to there cap name e.g. APPQA en APPPROD each with an IP's 10.110.250.1 and 10.110.250.2.

Actually it's the same WCF service but running on another baseadresss, like this example of our baseAdress:

```
<add baseAdress="net.tcp://appqa.domain.com:4504/.... 

and 

<add baseAdress="net.tcp://appprod.domain.com:4504/....
```

But when running these services on the **same** node we noticed that we were getting errors like there is Address is in use.

We found that weird because we added our alias in the base address section a nslookup of both our aliases and that gave us both the right IP address.

When running only the PROD service, I did a telnet command to the IP address of the QA and the 4504 port. I was able to make a connection this means that we are actually running on both IP adresses (or all addresses and port like 0:0:0:0:4504).

As an extra test we changed our baseadresses to

```
<add baseAdress="net.tcp://10.110.250.1:4504/.... 
<add baseAdress="net.tcp://10.110.250.2:4504/....
```

And then we can run both services next to each other on the same node, so we prove that our services work only the dns resolution does not work.

It all works in when we enable port sharing but we don't want do that because of a different SLA.

Has someone a idea how we can force WCF to use the IP address of his dns alias?